# How to move an entire collapsed level to another place in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste, editing, code

Given a document in Notepad++ with the following content:

[image]

For the sake of overview all elements are **collapsed**, like so:

[image]

When I want to move an entire `<element1>...</element1` around, I first select that line (say line nr 283, in its collapsed state(!)) and hit `Ctr+X` and then go to the bottom of the page, and hit `Ctr+V`.

However only the first line gets pasted `<element1><summary>Summary</summary>` instead of the entire collapsed element1!

How can one move around a **collapsed** elements in its entirety in Notepad++?
Without first having to uncollapse the element first!
Sothat no unnecessary uncollapsing-and-then-recollapsing are needed for every moving action.

Thanks for any alternative methods proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BEGIN/END Select` to select the start and end of your text then copy it. For example, if you want to copy element2, place the cursor at the beginning of the tag. Then right-click and select `BEGIN/END Select`. Then place the cursor at the line where the text ends in this case at the beginning of element3. Right-click and select `BEGIN/END Select`. Copy the text (Ctrl+C or right-click copy). The whole of element2 will be copied. You can then paste it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is just a little bit different to what you might think it is.

**Mouse usage:**
Instead of selecting the line from start of the line and move the mouse to the end of the line you select the start position and move the mouse one line down.

**Keyboard usage:**
Instead of pressing SHIFT+END you press SHIFT+Down Arrow.

- Place the cursor at the first column of the folded unique visible line
- Perform a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>
- Perform a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  **OR**  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Open a new tab <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> **OR** place the cursor for your needs
- Paste the clipboard contents <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

As expected, all contents of the folded section appears.